# Jquery insertBefore inserting text not HTML

Tags: javascript, jquery

The examples at http://api.jquery.com/insertbefore/ show insertBefore inserting new HTML into the DOM

My HTML is structured as follows:

```
        <div class="left line">
            <div class="steps" id="step1"></div>
        </div>
        <div class="left line">
            <div class="steps" id="step2"></div>
        </div>
```

I call this after the document is ready (Note I attempted to wrap the text in both "" and '' and got the same results. The code is running in a for loop and is inserting in the correct position.

```
        if (opts[i].payments1) {
            console.log("P1")
            $( "< div class = 'payment1'> < /div>" ).insertBefore( "#step" + i );

        }
```

when I run the code I get this

```
<div class="left line">
   &lt; div class = 'payment1'&gt; &lt; /div&gt;
  <div class="steps" id="step1" style="background-color: blue;"></div>
</div>
```

So when viewing the page I get

< div class = 'payment1'> < /div>

instead of the formatting of the div

Comment: don't put spaces into the html `<div` is a tag, `< div` isn't. since it's not a tag, jquery inserts it as text.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I assume `jQuery` doesn't like to way how you wrote `<div....`. Try

```
 $( "<div class='payment1'> </div>" ).insertBefore( $("#step" + i) );
```

get rid of spaces.

Comment: That was it. When I was working with Sublime earlier I told it to format my JavaScript spacing and indenting for me when I had the HTML just at the bottom to hold it and it added spaces so I did not noticed that. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

```
$("<div>").addClass("payment1").insertBefore( $("#step" + i) );
```